# The send_keys() method is neither working nor throwing any exception on the webpage's prompt type alerts

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

When trying to use the send_keys() method to enter the text in a webpage's prompt type alerts, it is doing nothing, nor any exceptoin is being thrown so that I can correct the issue. I have tried this on two different website where I get such prompts. I am using the Selenium version 4.8.2. The complete code is as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert

import sys
import time

def launch_browser(url:str = None, is_hidden = False) -> webdriver.Chrome:

    chromedriver_path = r"D:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_service = Service(chromedriver_path)

    browser_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = browser_path
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    
    if is_hidden != False: chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit()

    if url != None: driver.get(url)

    return(driver)

def sample_01():

    url = 'https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/alerts/'
    driver = launch_browser(url)

    element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'See a sample prompt')

    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5, poll_frequency=1).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(element)).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5, poll_frequency=0.5).until(ec.alert_is_present())
    alert = Alert(driver)

    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        alert.send_keys('Selenium')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    print(alert.text)
    
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()

def sample_02():
    url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt'

    driver = launch_browser(url)

    driver.switch_to.frame("iframeResult")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@onclick="myFunction()"]').click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 1).until(ec.alert_is_present())

    alert = Alert(driver)

    try:
        alert.send_keys('name_of_person')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    print(alert.text)
    time.sleep(5)

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_01()
    sample_02()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, keys are being sent, however the input text is not displayed in Chrome. See this chrome bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1120#c11

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didn't notice, that accepting the alert on w3school shows the send_keys() values although the same is not visible on the alert.